# Bootstrap : horizontal fields inside vertical form

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'd like to have some "horizontally styled" fields inside a "vertically styled" form with Bootstrap.

How can I do that (if possible)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can leverage Bootstrap's existing classes (`checkbox.inline`)to get the effect you're looking for. The key to making it look right is to specify `padding-left: 0px;` on the labels:

```
  <div class="control-group">
    <div class="controls">
      <label class="checkbox inline" style="padding-left: 0px;" for="inputColor">Favorite Color <input type="text" id="inputColor" class="span2" /></label>
      <label class="checkbox inline" style="padding-left: 0px;" for="inputNColor">Next Color <input type="text" id="inputNColor" class="span2" /></label>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Please see http://jsfiddle.net/jhfrench/Hzucn/ for a working example.

I tried to create a new class for you (along the lines of `.controls-row label.inline { padding-left: 0px;}` so you wouldn't have to do styling on the element, but it caused more conflicts than I anticipated. So if you're going to use this solution pervasively, you might want to invest the time in untangling that...

Answer (score 0):

You can use similar formatting to .form-horizontal implementation in bootstrap. (scroll sown to Horizontal Forms here: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms)

Wrap your labels and form elements in grouping divs (that's what .control-group does in Horizontal Form layout in bootstrap).

Float labels left to show them in horizontal alignment with the fields.

```
label.horizontal {
  float: left;
  width: 160px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  text-align: right;
}
```

In the above example, labels with class .horizontal will be "horizontally styled" and the rest "vertical" or default form layout.

Answer (score 0):

there is a class ready to use on bootstrap!

check this example:

```
<div class="span6">
  <form>
    <div class="controls controls-row">
      <input id="name" name="name" type="text" class="span3" placeholder="Name">
      <input id="email" name="email" type="email" class="span3" placeholder="Email address">
    </div>

   <div class="controls">
     <textarea id="message" name="message" class="span6" placeholder="Your Message" rows="5"></textarea>
   </div>

   <div class="controls">
     <button id="contact-submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary input-medium pull-right">Send</button>
   </div>

  </form>
</div>
```